# avplayer not playing audio with in IOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

i am trying to play a audiio with below code but its not playing. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

```
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&sessionError];
     [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
     AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:audioUrl]];
    [self setPlayer:[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item]];
    [[self player] setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];

    [[self player] play];
```

Comment: i am trying in simulator..

Comment: Solved by adding #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using ARC, you'll need to retain the AVAudioPlayer as it sets to nil automatically, which would be a likely reason for no sound. In your header file if you could make sure your self.player's property is set up like this,,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```

I hope this helps